# How to display an empty item of recyclerview so that user can fill the data into it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to kotlin-android and I am developing a stock keeping unit, where in one fragment i need to load the data into recycler view using arraylist but also, i need one blank item, where user can enter his own data and once he fills that blank item, a new blank item should be created.

```
    class RecyclerViewAdapterU (val dataList:ArrayList<ModelClass>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterU.ViewHolder>() {
    var _binding: UploadItemViewBinding? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecyclerViewAdapterU.ViewHolder {

        val v =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.upload_item_view, parent, false)
        _binding = UploadItemViewBinding.bind(v)

        return ViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    fun getUpdatedDetails(skucode:String,pos:Int){
       // val skuDetails:ArrayList<ModelClass>
        val call: Call<List<ModelClass>>? =
            ApiClient.instance?.myApi?.getfromsku(skucode)!!
        call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ModelClass>?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<ModelClass>?>,
                response: Response<List<ModelClass>?>
            ) {
                if (!response.body().isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    val skuDetails: ArrayList<ModelClass> = response.body() as ArrayList<ModelClass>
//
//                    if (!skuDetails.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        val x = dataList[pos].sku_code
                        if (skuDetails[pos].sku_code != x) {
                            //for (i in skuDetails.indices){
                            println(skuDetails[pos].sku_code)
                            println(".........$pos")

                            dataList.removeAt(pos)
                            dataList.add(pos, skuDetails[0])
                            skuDetails.clear()
                            notifyItemChanged(pos)

                            //}
                        }
                    }


            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ModelClass>?>, t: Throwable) {

            }
        })

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") position: Int) {


        bindItems(dataList[position])
        holder.getStock()
      holder.updateStockDetail()

    }
    fun bindItems(data: ModelClass) {

        binding.apply {
            itemquant.text=data.item_quant
            uploadItemName.text = data.item_name
            uploadMfg.text = data.mfg
            skuStock.setText(data.item_stock.toString())
             skuCode.setText(data.sku_code)
        }


    }



    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataList.size
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        fun getStock() {



            binding.skuStock.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
                override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                    if (binding.skuStock.isFocused){
                    for (i in 0 until RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected.size){
                        if (editable.toString().trim()!=""){
                            var x= editable.toString().trim().toInt()

                            RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].item_stock=x
                            //getting current itemstock before pushing update.
                            //assigning latest itemstock to the data for the update
                        }
                    }
                }}

            })
        }

        fun updateStockDetail(){
            binding.skuCode.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
                override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
                }
                override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                    //binding.skuCode.removeTextChangedListener(this)
                    var pos:Int=adapterPosition
                    var x= editable.toString().trim()


                    //RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].sku_code=x
                    println("$x in textwatcher and $pos")

                    //getting edited text and calling the function to get updated details.

                    getUpdatedDetails(x,pos)
                  // binding.skuCode.addTextChangedListener(this)

                }
            })

        }

    }
}
```

I have couple of bugs in the adapter too, for example, i cant change textwatcher more than once.
If somebody could help me with this, would be very glad.

`ob.data.selected` comes from another recyclerview adapter.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by using a different view type for the blank item that will always stay at the very top (or bottom if you prefer). Once the blank item is filled up then a new non-blank item with a different view type will be added to your list.

More info about view types here: [Android and Kotlin: RecyclerView with multiple view types](https://medium.com/@ivancse.58/android-and-kotlin-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types-65285a254393)